# Can I conditionally print statements to an external SAS program file?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following code, I am trying to generate a standalone code from the macro (written to an external sas file). However, by default the complete code is generated and written to the external file. I would like to know if there is a way by which one can control, which parts of the macro are written to the external file. Appreciate all the help I can get on this.

```
%macro tempmacro(outds=);

/* I dont want this following code to be printed */
    proc sql noprint;
        SELECT cats(name,"=",substr(name,2))
        INTO :renames SEPARATED BY " "
        FROM dictionary.columns
        WHERE LIBNAME="SASHELP" AND MEMNAME=upcase('BASEBALL');
    quit;

/* I only Want this following data step printed to the external file */
data &outds;
set sashelp.baseball;
rename &renames;
run;

%mend;


options mfile mprint;
filename mprint "D:\test_code.sas";
data _null_;
file mprint;
%tempmacro(outds=data1);
options nomfile nomprint;
run;
```

Comment: had to read that twice before I realised the implicit run group :-)  consider removing that last `run;` statement, or making it a more recognisable `run;quit;` terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `option nomprint` before your `proc sql` and then `option mprint` afterwards to restore it. For bonus UX points, check what the value of the option was before using `%sysfunc(getoption(mprint))` at the start of your macro, and restore it to the same value afterwards.